# How to implement web service with SOAP 1.1 in ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

I have to implement implement web service with SOAP 1.1 in ColdFusion. I am new in SAOP and searched for some example or sample code for web service in ColdFusion.

Didn't find any good tutorial with details. Just some portion of the code I got.
Don't know how to sent parameters and how to access those parameters inside web service methods.

Can I get some sample code or any link??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SOAP, you can follow this link,

http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2031328&seqNum=3

For REST, follow this link,

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html